# The requested URL /nagios/< was not found on this server

Tags: 16.04, apache2

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have just installed Nagios v4.1.1 but after logged in the portal it is showing me the error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /nagios/< was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

and at the left panel under current status, there also some errors are popping up:

> ```
> /tac.cgi" target="">Tactical Overview
> Map /statusmap.cgi?host=all" target="">(Legacy)
> /status.cgi?hostgroup=all&style=hostdetail" target="">Hosts
> /status.cgi?host=all" target="">Services
> /status.cgi?hostgroup=all&style=overview" target="">Host Groups
>     /status.cgi?hostgroup=all&style=summary" target="">Summary
>     /status.cgi?hostgroup=all&style=grid" target="">Grid
> /status.cgi?servicegroup=all&style=overview" target="">Service Groups
>     /status.cgi?servicegroup=all&style=summary" target="">Summary
>     /status.cgi?servicegroup=all&style=grid" target="">Grid
> /status.cgi?host=all&servicestatustypes=28" target="">Problems
>     /status.cgi?host=all&servicestatustypes=28" target="">Services (/status.cgi?host=all&type=detail&hoststatustypes=3&serviceprops=42&servicestatustypes=28"
> ```
>
> target="">Unhandled)
>           /status.cgi?hostgroup=all&style=hostdetail&hoststatustypes=12" target="">Hosts
>   (/status.cgi?hostgroup=all&style=hostdetail&hoststatustypes=12&hostprops=42"
>   target="">Unhandled)
>           /outages.cgi" target="">Network Outages
>
> /status.cgi" target="">

I am new for Ubuntu so sorry in advance for being less technical.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/19602970/

Comment: I have added my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file here

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/19603249/ -> nagios.conf

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/19603254/ -> 000-default.conf

Comment: "nagios.conf and 000-default.conf" These two conf files are from site-enabled directory